# Finding request id in cloudtrail for erronous API call in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudtrail

```
[cloudshell-user@ip-10-6-39-219 ~]$ <?xml version="1.0"?><ErrorResponse xmlns="http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-11-05/"><Error><Type>Sender</Type><Code>MissingParameter</Code><Message>The request must contain the parameter MessageBody.</Message><Detail/></Error><RequestId>a036828f-4b5f-50d0-9ee2-df9e[cloudshe[cloudshell-user@ip-10-6-39-219 ~]$  curl https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/632547665100/myqueue?Action=SendMessage&MessageBody=Your%20message%20text
```

How can I trace this request id: a036828f-4b5f-50d0-9ee2-df9e
I tried to find this in cloudtrail, but I could not find anything. Can anyone help me to find this request id, so I  know, what is going wrong?